# Nginx connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.128.1, server: hello-1.local

Tags: django, docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to setup ssl on my django + docker + nginx environment. However I encountered this error:

*19 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.128.1, server: hello-1.local, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://192.168.128.4:443/", host: "hello-1.local"

My Nginx config:

```
client_max_body_size 10M;

upstream web {  
  ip_hash;
  server web:443;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name hello-1.local;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {    
    
    location /static/ {    
        autoindex on;    
        alias /src/static/; 
    }

    location /media/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /src/media/;
    }

``

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://web/;
    }
    
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name hello-1.local;
    ssl_certificate /etc/certs/hello-1.local.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/certs/hello-1.local.key;
    
}
```

Yaml:

```
version: "3"

volumes:
  local_postgres_data: {}
  local_postgres_data_backups: {}

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: nz01
    ports:
      - 443:443
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
      - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./config/certs:/etc/certs
    depends_on:
      - web
    networks:
      - djangonetwork
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: compose/django/Dockerfile
    container_name: dz01
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
    expose:
      - 8000
    links:
      - redis
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.django
    networks:
      - djangonetwork
  db:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: compose/postgres/Dockerfile
    container_name: pz01
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.postgres
    volumes:
      - local_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - local_postgres_data_backups:/backups
    networks:
      - djangonetwork
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    container_name: rz01
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      - djangonetwork

networks:
  djangonetwork:
    driver: bridge
```

In browser, I get 502 Bad Gateway error and without ssl, the website run well. What could be the problem?

Comment: Looks like your upstream listens on port 8000, and most likely not ssl.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? @tkausl